# Need to make a call between multiple components in Angular 2

Tags: angular, plunker

I am trying to make an angular 2 project and need to make a call between multiple components. something like this

```
<ParentComponent>
    <ChildComponent>
        <ChildComponent 1>
        </ChildComponent 1>
    </ChildComponent> 
</ParentComponent>
```

I am trying to share information between ParentComponent and ChildComponent by using a component reference and trying to access properties and methods from the parent template.
I am able to see the field names of all three components in one form but  not able to access the value of childComponent in my parent form.

Form Value:

[image]

**[Here is my plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cHeVFGxWMI3XQp59suFN?p=preview)**

I am new to angular 2. Please help me how we can do this.

Comment: use `@output` decorator http://learnangular2.com/outputs/

Comment: can you update your post based on your plunker example **in place of the parent.. child.. child1..**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build your whole form in your parent, and then just pass the inner FormGroups to the child and grandchild. So your parent build the whole form:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm=this._fb.group({
        subAppName: ['', [Validators.required]],
        vendorDetails: this._fb.group({
         buildType: [''],
         primaryLang: [''],
         product: this._fb.group({
           vendorName: [''],
           productName: ['']
         })
       }),
        subAppType:['', [Validators.required]],
    });
}
```

And from your parent, pass the vendorDetails group to vendor component:

```ts
<subapp-vendor #vendortest [vendorDetails]='myForm.controls.vendorDetails'></subapp-vendor>
```

and use @Input in vendor for the formgroup:

```ts
@Input() vendorDetails: FormGroup;
```

and use that formGroup name in your view as well as the formcontrolnames you defined in the parent. Here you also pass the inner formGroup to the child component of this childcomponent, just like you did from the parent:

```ts
<div [formGroup]="vendorDetails">
      <label>Built Type</label>
      <div class="radio" *ngFor="let buildType of buildTypes">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" formControlName="buildType" [value]="buildType.value">
          {{buildType.display}}
        </label>
    </div>

  <subapp-product #producttest [product]="vendorDetails.controls.product"></subapp-product> 
    <label>Primary Language</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="primaryLang">
  </div>
```

aaaand then of course use @Input and the formGroup `product` in the view in product component just like above.

Here's your **[forked plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7tgVk16rr44tNMWl54jF?p=preview)**

Comment: PS. I suggest you change your title and content of question, since this is about dynamic forms and parent -> child -> child communication regarding that. That is quite different from your current question :)

Comment: You are very welcome! :) Since it solved your issue, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey tick under the voting of this answer :) https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235